# Different color in the same price plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, k-means, price

I have to color the price plot differently based on the cluster given by the `kmeans` function. Consider this code:

```
library(tseries)

####

nomiequity <- "^IXIC" 
datastart  <- "2019-09-18"

nsdq.prices <- get.hist.quote(instrument  = nomiequity,    
                              compression = "d",         
                              start       = datastart, 
                              end         = "2020-12-31", 
                              retclass    = "zoo",
                              quote       = "AdjClose")

b<-kmeans(nsdq.prices,3)
c<-b$cluster
d<- merge(nsdq.prices, c)
e<-split(nsdq.prices, c)

plot(nsdq.prices, type="l", col="green", ylim=c(6000, 13000))
    lines(e[["2"]], type = "l", col="red")
    lines(e[["3"]], type = "l", col="blue")
```

[image]
The result is almost what I need to do, but I don't want to show those connection between same colors in diffent time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the clusters get merged in the `line`s. You could use the `rle` lengths to increase the number by one when the clusters change in the time series. For this use `Map` to `rep`eat consecutive numbers `l` times. Then you are able to `split` on these growing numbers but use `cl`uster to define the color of the `lines`. For the latter use `lapply` to loop over the splitted `e`.

```
cl <- kmeans(nsdq.prices, 3)$cluster
l <- rle(as.numeric(cl))$lengths
s <- Map(rep, seq(l), l)
e <- split(cbind(nsdq.prices, cl), unlist(s))

plot(nsdq.prices, type="l", col=7, ylim=c(6000, 13000))
invisible(lapply(e, function(x) lines(x$Adjusted, col=x$cl + 1)))
legend("topleft", leg=c(sprintf("cl %s", 1:3), "missing"), col=c((1:3)+1, 7), lty=1)
```

[image]

Where there's no date defined there appear gaps. We could use the `zoo` interpolations by overplotting the original plot using a "missing" color.

Comment: Thank you jay.sf! So there's no way to keep the original shape of the chart without separating the various parts, right?

Comment: @Dani.Tav Probably not, since a line is one object and needs to be separated when needing different colors.

Comment: @Dani.Tav Or, if you mean the gaps, I slightly changed the code to get a continuous line.

Comment: Oh I see. I think I'll work on this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code helps you:

```
library(tseries)

####

nomiequity <- "^IXIC" 
datastart  <- "2019-09-18"

nsdq.prices <- get.hist.quote(instrument  = nomiequity,    
                              compression = "d",         
                              start       = datastart, 
                              end         = "2020-12-31", 
                              retclass    = "zoo",
                              quote       = "AdjClose")

b<-kmeans(nsdq.prices,3)
c<-b$cluster
d<- merge(nsdq.prices, c)
e<-split(nsdq.prices, c)


e3= e[['3']]
empty <- zoo(order.by=seq.Date(head(index(e3),1),tail(index(e3),1),by="days"))
e3=merge(e3,empty)


e2= e[['2']]
empty <- zoo(order.by=seq.Date(head(index(e2),1),tail(index(e2),1),by="days"))
e2=merge(e2,empty)


plot(nsdq.prices, type="l", col="green", ylim=c(6000, 13000))
lines(e2, type = "l", col="red")
lines(e3, type = "l", col="blue")
```

I just used this: [R: Filling missing dates in a time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555526/r-filling-missing-dates-in-a-time-series)

Comment: Thank you LocoGris! But the generated plot is the same as mine. The problem is that in the same "line" observations should be coloured differently without showing connections between non-adiacent observations of the same cluster.

Comment: Is geom_point not easier for visualisation in this case?
ggplot(d, aes(x = Index, y = Adjusted, col = as.factor(c))) + geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red", "blue"))

Comment: Thank you maarvd! This might be a good solutions, but there is a way to use lines instead of points?

Answer (score 0):

With this methodology I found the rows where cluster value changes, then selected those dates and added NA values for adjusted. geom_line breaks when NA values occur, hence giving the desired result.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

#add date as a column
datum <- index(d)
d <- as.data.table(d)
d$Datum <- datum

#add row number as a column
d$Row <- 1:nrow(d)

#find rows of d where cluster value changes
rows <- which(d$c != dplyr::lag(d$c))
rows <- d[Row %in% rows]

#add NA values for Adjusted at the Dates where values change(which breaks the geom_line)
rows <- rows[, Adjusted := NA]

#merge rows (NA values of Adjusted) with d
d <- rbind(rows, d)

#create a plot
ggplot(d, aes(x = Datum, y = Adjusted, col = as.factor(c))) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]